# Filter to scala springboot app

Tags: scala, spring-boot

I have simple webapp built using springboot and scala. I am able to create a simple rest API in my app. I am now trying to add a filter to support etags. However, I am unsuccessful in doing that. This is how my main app looks. Am I missing something in setting up the filter here?

```
object SampleApplication {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("SA:>>>>hello inside main");
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[Launcher]);
  }
}



@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
class Launcher extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  println("SA:>>>>>>inside Launcher beg")

  override def onStartup(servletContext: ServletContext): Unit = {
    println("SA:>>>>inside Launcher onStartup")
    servletContext.addFilter("etagFilter","org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter").addMappingForServletNames(null,false,"/*");
    //super.onStartup(servletContext)
  }

  override def configure(app: SpringApplicationBuilder): SpringApplicationBuilder = {
    println("SA:>>>>> inside Launcher")
    app.sources(classOf[Launcher])
    //super.configure(app)
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't override `onStartup` that breaks the `SpringBootServletInitializer`, next to that when using the `main` to boot the app the `SpringBootServletInitializer` isn't even used. Just add the filter as a bean to the configuration, Spring Boot will register it for you. This is also explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-and-filters) in the reference guide.

Comment: @M.Deinum - appreciate your reply. Posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @M. Deinum, got this working within few minutes. The filter gets hooked up fine with my app.

```
object SampleApplication {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[SampleConfig]);
  }
}

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Bean
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
class MyFilter extends ShallowEtagHeaderFilter{
}
```